# Finding value at indexes present in a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a 2D array size(2,3) and a list

**Input:**

```
a=['airplane','automobile','bird','cat','deer','dog','frog','horse','ship','truck']

b=[[4 2 8][1 7 0]] #2D numpy array shape (2,3) containing indices of list a
```

**Output:**

```
c = [['deer','bird','ship'],['automobile','horse','airplane']]
```

Is there any pythonic way or shortcut to achieve the output **without iterating over each index value**?

Comment: What are you going to do with the output? There might be a better way of representing your data.

Comment: it is just a[b] if a is converted in array.

Comment: why "without iterating over each index value"?  Is there a good reason for that restriction?

Comment: You can use `np.take` to have a 2D array as output : `np.take(a,b)`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I have got the array b after a number of operations on numpy array. Also the array b is of shape(n,3) where n is very large over 100000. So I am concerned about the time it will take to iterate using loop. But numpy operation will take less time for sure.

Comment: @B.M. I can change the a to array from list because it is fixed and takes less time to convert. Your solution is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your list a `np.array` as well, all you need is `a[b]`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> keys = np.array(['airplane','automobile','bird','cat','deer','dog','frog','horse','ship','truck'])
>>> indices = np.array([[4,2,8],[1,7,0]])
>>> keys[indices]
array([['deer', 'bird', 'ship'],
       ['automobile', 'horse', 'airplane']], 
      dtype='<U10')
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
a=['airplane','automobile','bird','cat','deer','dog','frog','horse','ship','truck']
b=numpy.array([[4,2,8],[1,7,0]])


c = [[a[idx] for idx in row] for row in b]
```

Comment: This iterates over each index.

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r Well, as `b` is a list you have to traverse and index. That's the whole point of a list.

Comment: I want to keep the array b as numpy array for further operations for my code

Comment: @Kapes I've edited my answer to make _b_ a numpy array.  This won't alter the rest of the code.  But I'm confused over what you want, or why this wouldn't be acceptable.  Keen to help if I can.

Comment: @ColinDickie see [Kapes response to why they don't want this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748369/finding-value-at-indexes-present-in-a-2d-array-in-python?noredirect=1#comment61079233_36748369)

Comment: @CPanda I totally agree. I just said "this iterates over each index" because OP wanted an answer to not use iteration.

Comment: Kapes,  glad you found a solution, and sorry for not reading the question and other comments fully.  I would be very interested in learning how much better @Eric solution performs.